# Incorrect datatype for database function in Lotus notes

Tags: database, function, lotus-notes, type-conversion

I have a Dialog Box field which has a Dblookup formula to look up the corresponding values.
Till yesterday it was working fine. This morning I have change a keyword from the lookup view and while clicking the dialog box I receive the error in the Dialog box as "Incorrect datatype for database function". I tried every possibilities but still unable to crack the issue. Can some one help?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue by myself. Here is what the actual dblookup formula written in the Dialog Box field.
*Dblookup("";"DBname";"ViewName";"Key";"ColumnNumber)*

after tireless troubleshooting I later found it to be very silly mistake that I did not check in the beginning. The lookup did not have any **cache** mentioned which should be "NoCache". So I changed it like this in the below and has worked. 
*Dblookup("":"NoCache";"DBname";"ViewName";"Key";"ColumnNumber)*